# Visual Studio - Summary Tag Comments - Optional Params

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio, xml-comments

When specifying summary tag comments, is there a way with the `<param>` tag to note that a parameter is optional, ie. the client can supply a value or null, such as: `<param name="Mime"  optional="true">.`

Googling has failed to provide me with a set list of attributes or allowed values.

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets data associated with instance
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Key">The key defining the data</param>
/// <param name="Value">The data</param>
/// <param name="Mime">The mime type of the data (optional)</param>     <----- Mark as optional
```

Thanks

Comment: Overloading was considered, however I decided against it in this particular example.

Comment: This method is part of an interface, I felt that adding an additional overload for such as small detail would just clutter the interface.

Comment: I was also curious whether this type of commenting was supported with the addition of the new optional parameter available in .NET 4.0 (as mentioned below).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. The only attribute being recognized by VS is the `name`, like that:

```
<param name="FileName" >The filename of the file to be loaded.</param>
```

The only thing that you can do - is to set [xsl transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx) for your output document. But this won't have any effect on Intellisense.

Answer (score 4):

You should provide an overload that omits the optional parameter:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets data associated with the instance using the default media type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key">The key defining the data.</param>
/// <param name="value">The data.</param>
public void SetData(object key, object value)
{
    SetData(key, value, null);
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets data associated with the instance using the specified media type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key">The key defining the data.</param>
/// <param name="value">The data.</param>
/// <param name="mime">The media type of the data.</param>
public void SetData(object key, object value, string mime)
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can declare the parameter as optional:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets data associated with the instance.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key">The key defining the data.</param>
/// <param name="value">The data.</param>
/// <param name="mime">The media type of the data.</param>
public void SetData(object key, object value, string mime = null)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<remarks></remarks>` tag. Doesn't exist special tag for optional params.